# Show Outlook 2016 Calendar reminders in notification centre

Tags: macos, ms-office, notifications, office-365

Is it possible to show Calender events and reminders from an Office 365 account set up in Outlook 2016 under the macOS Notification Centre? I can't seem to find a way to add them here